# How to bypass Cloudflare with Puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer, cloudflare

I am trying to scrape some startups data of a site (bestsecret.at) with Puppeteer and when I try to navigate to the next page the Cloudflare waiting screen comes in and disrupts the scraper. Is there a way to bypass it with Puppeteer?

[image]

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth'); 
const randomUseragent = require('random-useragent');
const userAgent = randomUseragent.getRandom();
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

(async () => {
    var argarr = ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'];

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: argarr});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.setUserAgent(userAgent);
    await page.goto('https://www.bestsecret.at', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'}); 
    const bodyWidth = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.scrollWidth);
    const bodyHeight = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.scrollHeight);
    await page.setViewport({ width: bodyWidth, height: bodyHeight });
      
    await page.type('#login-username', 'USARENAME');
    await page.type('#j_password', 'PASSWORD');

    await page.waitForTimeout(1000); 
    await Promise.all([
       page.click('#login-button'),
       page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle2'}),
    ]); 

    let bodyHTML = await page.content();
    console.log(bodyHTML);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: You can't, that is the whole point of this type of protection offered by CloudFlare (to prevent scrapers like you), unless you know the actual hostname or IP address of the machine hosting the actual, you can only go through CloudFlare.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel and even if they new the origin server IP, it's trivial for the server to block requests that didn't pass through Cloudflare.

Comment: Does that mean there is no way or plugin to bypass cloudflare with Puppeteer?

Answer (score 0):

Things you could try are:

- use {headless: false} in puppeteer launch (maybe with xvfb)
- connect through a residential connection (maybe a proxy)